# How to write the VIN Scanner tool

Tags: iphone, image-processing, image-manipulation

I have a requirement where I have to scan the VIN barcode. Can anyone guide me how to proceed. Its an iPhone Requirement.

Comment: You need to supply a boatload more information than this before any reasonable answer can be given.

Comment: not necessarily: checkout my answer below. it works great ive been using it for a couple of months now, and its completely free

Answer (score 0):

http://www.softeksoftware.co.uk/en/news/204-vin-barcode-reader-for-the-iphone.html

Does this help?

Be careful that (at least in the UK) the DVLA will not be happy with you releasing an app containing anything that scans Vehicle registration information.